# Unable to convert .row in vb.net?

Tags: datagridview, datagrid, grid, row

I want to convert `.row property` of `vsflexGrid` in `vb.net` while using `DataGridView` .

```
 If Len(Trim(stRC)) = 0 Then
                        .Row = 1
                         .TopRow = .Row
                    Else
```

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: i am converting project from vb6 to vb.net and am unable to find the solution for converting .row property of vsflexgrid to datagridview